# Can't align ionicons inside span element

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
<span class="tag label label-warning custom-class">label 1<span class="ion-ios-close-empty close"></span></span>
<span class="tag label label-warning custom-class">label 2<span class="ion-ios-close-empty close"></span></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle
   }

.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
    display:inline-block;
   }

.custom-class { 
   margin: 1px; padding-right: 1.5rem;
   }

.close { 
  font-size: 2rem; position: relative; top: 0.4rem; left: 1rem
  }
```

Here's a codepen with the necessary css files loaded:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooWwpe

I'm not sure if including a `span` inside a `span` for the icon is the right way. But I need the icon to be it's own element so it can be clicked.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I need the icon to be it's own element so it can be clicked", it's clickable, see: https://codepen.io/commercialsuicide/pen/bYWRmJ?editors=1010

Comment: Yes but the icon isn't properly aligned with the label.

Comment: You want both of them to be vertically aligned in the middle?

Comment: I want the icon to be aligned horizontally with the label. The label char length is dynamic, that's why I've added a right padding in the `.custom-class` for the ion icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is: https://codepen.io/commercialsuicide/pen/vWmZPr

Just give negative `top` rule to `.close` elements, because they have too much height by default.

Answer (score 1):

I would use absolute positioning for the close icon. This way it's taken out of the document flow and will not affect the height of the tag/label.

```css
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 1.3rem;
}

.custom-class {
  margin: 1px;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}
.close {
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: .25rem;
  top: -.1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
  <span class="tag label label-warning custom-class">label 1<span class="ion-ios-close-empty close"></span></span>
  <span class="tag label label-warning custom-class">label 2<span class="ion-ios-close-empty close"></span></span>
</div>
```