# Align Ionicons with Text

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionicons

I am not sure how to align my Ionicons with the text. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250500/cant-align-ionicons-inside-span-element) but I am rarely working with CSS so can not make sense of it...

How can I get the vertical center of the ionicon aligned with the text inside the `ion-col` item? The alignment of the first `ion-col` cell is broken too...

Code

```
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="3">
                23C
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size="3">Text
                <ion-icon name="arrow-up-outline" size="small"
                    [ngStyle]="{'transform': 'rotate(180deg)'}">
                </ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size="3">Text
                <ion-icon name="arrow-up-outline" size="small"
                    [ngStyle]="{'transform': 'rotate(45deg)'}">
                </ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
```

[image]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to align your icons and texts. I gave a class name to ion-col to apply flexbox only to that elements.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY7MW.jpg

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col size="3">
      23C
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col class="my-class" size="3">Text
      <ion-icon name="arrow-up-outline" size="small" [ngStyle]="{'transform': 'rotate(180deg)'}"></ion-icon>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col class="my-class" size="3">Text
      <ion-icon name="arrow-up-outline" size="small" [ngStyle]="{'transform': 'rotate(45deg)'}"></ion-icon>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

```
  ion-row {
    display:flex; 
  }
  ion-col {
    padding:10px;
  }
  .my-class {
    display: flex;    
  }
```